# Make DIV span height of inner H3 and DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have a layout like such ...

```
<div style="width: 99%; border: 1px dotted #0683DA; padding: 8px;">
    <h3>Some Header</h3>
    <div class="d-dataGridBodyRow" style="padding: 0px">
        <table style="vertical-align: top;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" id="ErrMsg" runat="server">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 15%;">
                    <p class="FieldLabel">
                        Field 1:</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Field1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 15%;">
                    <p class="FieldLabel">
                        Field 2:</p>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Field2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 15%;">
                    <p class="FieldLabel">
                        Field 3:</p>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Field3Validator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Field3"
                        ErrorMessage="Some message." ValidationExpression="^\d{16}"
                        EnableClientScript="true" CssClass="errortext" />
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Field3" runat="server" MaxLength="16"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 15%;">
                    <p class="FieldLabel">
                        Field 4:</p>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Field4Validator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Field4"
                        ErrorMessage="Some message."
                        ValidationExpression="\A[A-HJ-NPR-Z\d]{11}\d{6}\z" EnableClientScript="true"
                        CssClass="errortext" />
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Field4" runat="server" MaxLength="17"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 15%;">
                    <p class="FieldLabel">
                        Field 5:</p>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Field5Validator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Field5"
                        ErrorMessage="Some message."
                        ValidationExpression="\A[A-HJ-NPR-Z\d]{11}\d{6}\z" EnableClientScript="true"
                        CssClass="errortext" />
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Field5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 15%;">
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <div class="d-formSubmitCont" style="padding-right: 20px;">
                        <!-- <asp:LinkButton CssClass="b-primaryBtnArrow" ID="Cancel" runat="server"><span>Cancel</span></asp:LinkButton> -->
                        <asp:LinkButton CssClass="b-primaryBtnArrow" ID="Find" runat="server" OnClick="Find_Click"
                            CausesValidation="true"><span>Find</span></asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

... however the outer `div` only spans the height of the `h3`, how do I get it to span the height of the inner `div` as well?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cqXPZ/ Seems to be fine , your inner div has nothing.

Comment: Is this browser specific?  It seems to be working in FF if you give the inner div some content. http://jsfiddle.net/8z3y5/

Comment: @freebird, you're right. Let me edit the question to see if I can give some more information. I didn't think the rest was relevant at the moment, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have a CSS rule that is making `.d-dataGridBodyRow` float. If this is the case and you want the outer `<div>` to fully enclose it, an easy way is to give it the CSS `overflow: hidden`. If that is not possible (you explicitly want overflow content) try [the standard clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html).

Comment: This worked perfectly, great job. Next time I'll be sure to include the runtime **applied** CSS in the question. The `.d-dataGridBodyRow` was in fact floated left - the `overflow: hidden` on the outer div worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. If it fixed your problem then don't forget to upvote/accept!

Answer (score 1):

The inner `div` has no contents that is why it is not occupying any space. Change it to:

```
<div style="width: 99%; border: 1px dotted #0683DA; padding: 8px;">
    <h3>Some Header</h3>
    <div class="d-dataGridBodyRow" style="padding: 0px">&nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, just refresh the browser on the question. I added more code.

Comment: Yep, it appears that @meustrus inferred what was going on. Next time I post an HTML and CSS question I'll be sure to include the runtime CSS styles.

Answer (score 1):

Give 100% height to inner div

```
<div class="d-dataGridBodyRow" style="padding: 0px; height:100%">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put something in your div the height will stretch.

```
<div style="width: 99%; border: 1px dotted #0683DA; padding: 8px;">
    <h3>Some Header</h3>
    <div class="d-dataGridBodyRow" style="padding: 0px">
        Hello World
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the second div a height, or put some content in there. Currently it is taking up no space hence why no space is shown.